# Capturing an element image in a chrome extension (failing with zoom)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot, zooming

I'm trying to get the image/screenshot of a specific element in a chrome extension, the problem I'm having is that when I'm cropping the result from `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` the resulting image is off if the page is zoomed in/out (Via `View -> Zoom In`).

Specially the problem is that because the page is zoomed the offsets/sizes I get from the content script aren't scaled up/down so I end up cropping the wrong area of the screenshot

Is there a way to get/set a tabs current zoom level? Or detect the correct element size/position?

Everything I found on google points to no, but awesome screenshot makes this work somehow

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, { format: "png" }, function(dataUrl) {
            console.log('got capture');
            if (!canvas) {
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                console.log('created canvas');
            }
            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function() {
                console.log('image loaded, cropping');
                canvas.width = dimensions.width;
                canvas.height = dimensions.height;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(image,
                    dimensions.left, dimensions.top,
                    dimensions.width, dimensions.height,
                    0, 0,
                    dimensions.width, dimensions.height
                );
                console.log('image created');
                var croppedDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    url: croppedDataUrl,
                    windowId: tab.windowId
                });
            }
            image.src = dataUrl;
        });
```

content-script:

```
console.log('getting dimensions')
                var dimensions = {
                    top: -window.scrollY + $(element).offset().top,
                    left: -window.scrollX + $(element).offset().left,
                    width: $(element).width(),
                    height: $(element).height()
                };
                console.log('sending dimensions', dimensions);
                sendResponse(dimensions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a sample extension here and it worked perfectly with Zoom in and Zoom out as well. It **always** `captured visible Tab` perfectly. If you are looking at adjusting zoom level you can try `document.body.style.zoom = "Your_value%";` However you need to put this code through `content script` to get it running for `chrome extensions`

Sample code that worked

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "Screen Shot",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This will generate Screen Shot of current Chrome Page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "screen.png",
    "default_popup": "script.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "icons":{"16":"screen.png","48":"screen.png","128":"screen.png"}
}
```

***script.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="button.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
body{
margin:0px;
width:0px;
height:0px;
border:0px;
}
</style>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***button.js***

```
function screenshot() {
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{format:"jpeg",quality:100},function(dataUrl){
    window.open(dataUrl);
});
}
screenshot();
```

Comment: The problem is that the offsets/sizes are wrong when the page is zoomed in and it crops out the wrong part of the page

Comment: And setting the zoom % via CSS doesn't seem to remove the zooming caused by Chrome

Comment: @ChrisT: Have you tried setting styles for zoom offset etc through content scripts, when i customize the values it worked here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a Range Object and Range.getBoundingClientRect() to appropriately account for zoom.

```
console.log('getting dimensions')
var r=new Range();//could be done elsewhere reuse
r.selectNode(element);
var dimensions = r.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log('sending dimensions', dimensions);
sendResponse(dimensions);
```

you may have to copy dimensions over to a base js object to get it to send properly.

another option would be to use chrome.tabs.getZoom to adjust the dimensions.